# What is $|a_n|$ of the power series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n + 1} x^{2n + 1}$

Tags: real-analysis

What is $|a_n|$ of the power series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n + 1} x^{2n + 1}$?

A power series has the form $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, so $|a_n| = \frac{1}{2n + 1}$ in this case. My professor wrote $|a_n|$ as a piece-wise function:

$|a_n| =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if n even }  \\ 
\frac{1}{n}{} & \text{ if n odd } 
\end{cases}
$

I don't really understand how he got those?

Comment: The coefficient of $x^n$ is...?

Answer (score 1):

The powers of $x$ in your series is the set $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...\}.$ You see, it contains no even numbers. That's why you can say it's $|a_n| = 0$ if $n$ is even and $\frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ odd.

Answer (score 0):

.......**hint**: what are the coefficients of the terms $a_{2n}x^{2n}$ ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{4n + 1}$? I don't really follow...

Comment: I am still unclear on why the coefficients of even terms are 0. So $a_1 = -\frac{1}{3}, a_2 = -\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5}, a_3 = -\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7}$ and so forth...I am still not really seeing it